# Upload resulting gif of AMPscript BarcodeURL() to content builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, ampscript, ssjs, barcode

I want to send a member card as barcode via SFMC/Whatsapp. However, Whatsapp content does not allow the use of the BarcodeURL() function to generate the barcode image. My plan now is to use a code resource to create an endpoint that creates the image and uploads it to content builder via API which then gives me the published URL. I created the code resource which successfully generates and returns a BarcodeImageURL when I pass the member number. However, this BarcodeImageURL is not a direct link to a file but the barcode .gif seems to be generated when making the GET request. Now I'm stuck at the step where I need to do an HTTPGet to the BarcodeImageURL and convert the response into valid base64 that I can upload via API. The response is some type of binary that I can't seem to properly parse with SSJS, I think it's pretty much the same as [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/81438/ampscript-js-base64encode-for-images-create-wrong-code). I actually found a [piece of code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10982712/convert-binary-data-to-base64-with-javascript/68172185#68172185) that does exactly what I want for "modern browsers" in client side javascript, I need that blob() method. [This is an example](https://cl.s50.exct.net/LiveContent.aspx?qs=310419e19c5736e81cb9a00e320e5bc55f27da836c4a64763461a644a2e960986919b098687b20d51c7fb939876c0f0cc119e4b8b95d8e79b3ed0bbfcd47a376550bdacb3ea47e556100efd9805b43d9) of a BarcodeImageURL. Does anyone know how I can manage this?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not possible with SSJS as it cannot properly interpret binary file data. Recommended route would be to use some kind of serverless function on AWS/GCP/Azure.